# Using dynamic expression as claimCheck key

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to use the claimCheck but pass a dynamic key which would be 
something unique like the filename in my input message or the 
breadcrumbId. But it seems this processor doesn't support this?

e.g)

`.claimCheck(ClaimCheckOperation.Set, "${headers.CamelFileName}", "body")`

Is there a way to use the simple method but return a string e.g)

```
simple("${headers.CamelFileName}").toString()
```

but evaluate the expression at runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: No this is not supported at this time. Claus just implemented this feature ([CAMEL-13599](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13599), [commit](https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/8d714faaf1d12b60ae701da1544db708881f8d1c)) a few minutes ago and it will be released in Camel 3.0.0-M3

Comment: This has already been posted, and answered on the user mailing list at Apache Camel